# What exactly does valid_size, f_stable, n_stable do in scikit-neuralnetwork fitting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, perceptron, scikits

What exactly does `valid_size`, `f_stable`, `n_stable` do in scikit-neuralnetwork fitting?

I'm trying to use scikit-neuralnetwork for a regression problem. I have read all the documentation I can find, but I don't quite understand what the `n_stable, f_stable,` and `valid_size` input parameters mean.

If we use `n_stable = 100`, `f_stable = .001`, and `valid_size = .1`, does this mean it will [1] divide the set into 90% training; [2] make a step (change parameters) using gradient descent; [3] then test on the other 10% of the data; [4] if that test mean_squared_error is less than .001, then it counts that iteration towards the n_stable quota of 100-- yes? or is it something else?

More generally, this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957564/configuration-of-neural-network-for-regression-using-scikit-neuralnetwork

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainers of the sknn github page asked me to post this as an issue. It's here with some explanations https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/issues/117